# Why do we install a library via pip and again add it in pycharm under project settings?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I installed the selenium package via pip and again in the pycharm ide.

Why do we add the selenium package under the project setting? What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "add to project settings". Are you using a different interpreter in PyCharm? That would be the only reason to need to change how you install something

Comment: @OneCricketeer my question is there any difference between installing packages via pip and pycharm..? I can use either of them to install my packages right..? and yes I am using python interpreter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my question is there any difference between installing packages via pip and pycharm..? I can use either of them to install my packages right..? Briefly I want to know if there is any difference between installing package via pip and installing packages via pycharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm redirects to calling pip internally. The only difference would be that Pycharm allows you to set project specific interpreters, which you'd need to first manually activate in the terminal in order to install packages to them, rather than your default/system interpreter